# ¿Por qué la variable "rango" me sale que no existe dentro del contexto actual en C#? Psdt: Estoy comenzando en C#

Tags: c#

[image]

Este es el problema que tengo, si se fijan, la variable "rango" me la marca con error, y es porque esta fuera del contexto actual de C#. Alguien me podría explicar el por qué, por favor.

Comment: A la hora de añadir código no uses imágenes, añádelo en texto plano.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Porque estás definiendo la variable rango dentro del contexto del if.

Tienes que definirla una sola vez, antes del primer if y luego solo reasignarle valores.

```
int rango;

if (num >= 1 & num <= 9){
    rango = 1;
}
```

Por cierto, no subas una imagen del codigo, mejor copia el texto.

Comment: Si me funciono, ¡muchas gracias!
Gracias por la recomendación.